# Using python enumerate() to equate list elements

Tags: python

I want to do something of the form:

```
for index,value in enumerate('xyz'):
    [x,y,z][index] = [dict1.get(value),dict2.get(value),dict3.get(value)][index]
```

But of course this doesn't work.

I'd like to take an input string and match each character to a dictionary, then assign the corresponding dictionary value to a variable. Consider the following function:

```
def parse_options(options):
    dir_pref,file_pref,name_pref = None,None,None
    for idx,char in enumerate(options):
        # match key characters from input 'options' string to dictionaries
        if char in [dir_options.keys(),file_options.keys(),name_options.keys()][idx]:
            [dir_pref,file_pref,name_pref][idx] = \
            [dir_options.get(char),file_options.get(char),name_options.get(char)][idx]
    return [dir_pref,file_pref,name_pref]
```

Which, at present, returns `(None,None,None)`

This is a renaming script. `options` is a string object where the first character of the string tells my script how it should iterate over directories; the second character tells my script how it should choose which files to operate on; and the third character tells my script how it should rename the files. I want to match each of the characters in `options` to a corresponding dictionary (`dir_options`,`file_options` and `name_options`, respectively) and assign their corresponding dictionary values to three new variables (`dir_pref`,`file_pref` and `name_pref`)

It may be that there is a much better way to go about this, in which case I'd love to hear suggestions

Comment: As far as I know, with *iterable unpacking*, you **can't specify an additional index**.

Comment: I don't know if it is just me, but I don't understand this at all. I have no idea what is trying to be done, and what the final expected result is supposed to be.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do in the long run can be done much better than what you're trying to do

Comment: Trying to think of a better way to phrase the question… for each loop in the enumeration, I want to set one element of one list to equal one element of the other list. I want  `enumerate()` to determine which elements should be equated (using the index it returns).

Comment: @corvus Please provide a sample input, and a sample expected output. You need to illustrate this better with proper examples. If someone else here understands this, maybe they will provide an answer, but at least for myself, I still have no idea what's happening.

Comment: @idjaw, I've tried to edit my question to make it more clear. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Terry_A Probably so, I am a novice to python and I'm very open to hearing any suggestions you might have

Comment: Do you mean to do `[idx % 3]` otherwise you either only have 0 - 3 items in `options` or you get `IndexError`. If you only have 0 - 3 items then I don't see the need for the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pick which variable to assign to by indexing a list. Assigning to `[x, y, z][1]` doesn't assign to `y`; it assigns to a list cell in a list that just gets thrown away.

Instead of all that stuff you're doing, get rid of most of those variables and just build the returned list directly:

```
def parse_options(options):
    return [d.get(char)
            for d, char in zip([dir_options, file_options, name_options], options)]
```

The `dir_pref`, `file_pref`, and `name_pref` variables are completely unnecessary. Also, `get` returns `None` by default if the key isn't present, so you don't need an explicit check.

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you for cutting through the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to handle `KeyError` with this method? (i.e. if a key was not found in the dictionary, I'd like to pass the key character itself as a string)

Comment: @corvus: `dict.get` takes an optional second argument specifying what to return when the key isn't present, if the default `None` isn't what you want.